# Rails json column in postgresql not accepting any value, and returning nil when called after storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, postgresql, hash

I was not certain of an easy way to boil down the initial question. I am attempting to convert a nested hash type of object to a form that can be stored in PG by active record. I have tried the gem "nested-hstore", but could not get it to work. Have tried serializing the column, etc... The object itself is a multidimensional array containing Objects. I believe that converting the MD Array to a nested hash type of structure where the keys represent the combined indices of the MD array correspond directly to the Object the contain should be easiest for a JSON conversion. The structure contains a lot of data, so I think that might be throwing PG/ActiveRecord off, or maybe I am missing an important aspect of the syntax.

Here is the code for creating a database entry then testing its call:

```
Turn.create(turn: @counter, board: arrHash.to_json, games_id: 
            @@current_game.id)
turner = Turn.where(turn:@counter).first
puts turner.board
```

Here is the migration/table:

```
class CreateTurns < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :turns do |t|
      t.integer :turn
      t.json :board, default: "{}" 
      t.references :games, foreign_key: true, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Any help with either a better strategy for storing this, or perhaps a syntactical difference that I might be completely overlooking would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `where` returns a relation, you need `Turn.where(turn:@counter).to_a` or `Turn.where(turn:@counter).last`, etc.

Comment: sorry, I was initially using .first, have been trying a few different things to see if it will give me hints.

Comment: what is the output now of `turner.border`?  can you also do `create!` and show us the logs?

Comment: Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 66ms (ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Game must exist): ---this is with create! instead of create it suggests the entity is not processable, and with basic create method the field is not returned by the query at all.

Comment: and if you do `Turn.create!(turn: @counter, board: arrHash.to_json, game: 
            @@current_game)` ?

Comment: yes, the log returns 422 Unprocessable entity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161834/discussion-between-anthony-and-chad-d).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so yes, the issue was that the variable in the belongs_to attribute for Turn class was not in plural form, and this was keeping the turns from properly being saved. The to_json method works well for saving to PG. Thanks to Anthony for helping me out, I have completed the functionality that I was implementing.